# android authentication in real world

Tags: android, authentication

So I learned the basics of android but I never understood this part.
I know when using websites, authentications are made along side `sessions` and `cookies`. But what about android?

When an authentication is made, a token is generated, right? where does this token belongs in android application world? is it stored in `AccountManager` ? should it be stored on `SharedPreferences` ? I also saw something called `OAuth2` but didn't get what that is.

I'm sorry if my question is stupid but it is driving me nuts in a long time.

if you have a good tutorial for these kinds of web services, where they teach real world coding examples, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most modern Android apps use HTTP client to do backend calls, for instance `Retrofit`. I would suggest reading a bit about `Retrofit` and about how you can use this token
More about authentication token and `Retrofit`, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=by-pChg9_A4)

As to where to save the token, in my current project I save the token in something similar to a static field. more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43937054/1390881)